# join columns separated by delimiter in same table

Tags: sql, join, union

I have the following data set

```sql
color_code   fav_color_code    color_code_name    fav_color_name 
1|2          5                 blue|white         black
3|4          7|9               green|red          pink|yellow
```

I need to `join` first value of `color_code` to first value of `color_code_name` and second value of `color_code` to second value of `color_code_name` etc..

```sql
code                color
1                   blue
2                   white
5                   black
3                   green
4                   red
7                   pink
9                   yellow
```

I am using the below code, but it is doing cross join since I dont have an `id` to `join` upon. This code work if I am mapping 2 columns but not multiple columns.

Could someone help me to get the expected result?

```sql
SELECT 
        t1.code AS code, 
        t2.color AS color, 
      FROM 
        (
          SELECT 
            c.value :: varchar AS code, 
            row_number() over(
              order by 
                code
            ) AS rownum 
          FROM 
            table, 
            lateral flatten (
              input => split(color_code, '|')
            ) c  
          UNION 
          SELECT 
            d.value :: varchar AS code, 
            row_number() OVER(
              ORDER BY 
                code
            ) AS rownum
            FROM 
            table, 
            lateral flatten (
              input => split(fav_color_code, '|')
            ) d 
        ) t1 
        JOIN (
          SELECT 
            f.value :: varchar AS color, 
            row_number() OVER(
              ORDER BY 
                color
            ) AS rownum 
          FROM 
            table, 
            lateral flatten (
              input => split(color_code_name, '|')
            ) f 
          UNION 
          SELECT 
            g.value :: varchar AS color, 
            row_number() OVER(
              ORDER BY 
                color
            ) AS rownum 
          FROM 
            table, 
            lateral flatten (
              input => split(fav_color_name, '|')
            ) g 
        ) t2 ON (t1.rownum = t2.rownum) 
      ORDER BY 
        t1.color
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this approach in several steps for explanation purposes, because I think in one step is a mess.

**NOTE:**
The code solution is done in `Hive`(the `post` doesn't specify any `sql-query-engine`), but in `Hive` almost everything is `sql-standard`.

Original data

```sql
+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+--+
| colors.color_code  | colors.fav_color_code  | colors.color_code_name  | colors.fav_color_name  |
+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+--+
| 1|2                | 5                      | blue|white              | black                  |
| 3|4                | 7|9                    | green|red               | pink|yellow            |
+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+--
```

First we create a `temp table` with `color ids` where we concatenate the `code columns`, `split` the column into an `array` and then `explode` the `array` with a `rownumber`

```sql
CREATE TABLE tc1 AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rownum, CAST(color_id AS INT) as color_id
FROM colors
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(SPLIT(CONCAT(color_code,'|', fav_color_code),'\\|')) a1 AS color_id;
```

We create a second `temp table` with `color names` and we follow the approach as before but now we concatenate the `color_name` columns, `split` the column into an `array` and then `explode` the `array` with a `rownumber`

```sql
CREATE TABLE tc2 AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rownum, color_name
FROM colors
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(SPLIT(CONCAT(color_code_name,'|', fav_color_name),'\\|')) a1 AS color_name;
```

we `join` temp tables by `rownum`

```sql
SELECT color_id, color_name
FROM tc1
JOIN tc2 ON(tc1.rownum = tc2.rownum)
ORDER BY color_id;
```

Expected output

```sql
+-----------+-------------+--+
| color_id  | color_name  |
+-----------+-------------+--+
| 1         | blue        |
| 2         | white       |
| 3         | green       |
| 4         | red         |
| 5         | black       |
| 7         | pink        |
| 9         | yellow      |
+-----------+-------------+--+
```

Doing the same thing in one shot, though is not a light-weight query

```sql
SELECT tc1.color_id, tc2.color_name
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rownum, CAST(color_id AS INT) as color_id
      FROM colors
      LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(SPLIT(CONCAT(color_code,'|', fav_color_code),'\\|')) a1 AS color_id) AS tc1
JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rownum, color_name
      FROM colors
      LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(SPLIT(CONCAT(color_code_name,'|', fav_color_name),'\\|')) a1 AS color_name) AS tc2
ON(tc1.rownum = tc2.rownum)
ORDER BY tc1.color_id;
```

Expected output

```sql
+---------------+-----------------+--+
| tc1.color_id  | tc2.color_name  |
+---------------+-----------------+--+
| 1             | blue            |
| 2             | white           |
| 3             | green           |
| 4             | red             |
| 5             | black           |
| 7             | pink            |
| 9             | yellow          |
+---------------+-----------------+--+
```